# dplyr sql -- reading from multiple schemas without copy == TRUE

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I have large tables in two different schemas inside the same Greenplum Postgresql database which I want to join using dplyr. I cannot provide a reproducible example because it involves proprietary data, but I can provide code (with names suitably changed).

In SQL this would be

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM schema1.table1
INNER JOIN schema2.table2
ON schema1.table1.column_name=schema2.table2.column_name;
```

Using dplyr, this is

```
my_db <- src_postgres(host = "s.net", user = "id",password = "xxx",dbname="db1",  options="-c search_path=schema1") 
my_db_src <- src_postgres(host = "s", user = "id", password = "xxx", dbname="db1",  options="-c search_path=schema2") 

tbl1 <- tbl(my_db, "table1")
tbl1 <- tbl(my_db_src, "table2")
cc_compare <- inner_join(tbl1 ,tbl2,by="customerid",copy=TRUE)
```

I'd like to join them in dplyr without using copy == TRUE, which takes a long time. Can dplyr accomplish this and if so how?

Comment: no reproducible data? and how large is the data?

Comment: data.table join would be fast.  Some reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: just made an edit to clarify. no reproducible data. @akrun data.table doesn't seem to do SQL queries, just operations on local data already in memory, right?